# TypeScript and SystemJS: main file can't use more than one import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to set up a TypeScript application that loads its modules into a main module(main.ts). This works OK if main.ts only has one import, but if I import a second module in main.ts, an error is thrown in the browser console when I try to utilise that module.

```
browser...11.2.js (line 1)
Error: @http://localhost:3000/src/person.ts!transpiled:1:63
    @http://localhost:3000/src/person.ts!transpiled:1:1
    @http://localhost:3000/src/person.ts!transpiled:1:1 
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/src/person.ts
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/src/person.ts as "./person" from http://localhost:3000/src/main.ts
```

The code in my SystemJS script tag

```
System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript',
      packages: {
          src: {
              defaultExtension: 'ts'
          }
      }
  });
  System
          .import('src/main.ts')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The main.ts file, which throws the above error

```
import {Person} from './person';
import {Batman} from './batman';

let person = new Person();
console.log(person.name);

let bat = new Batman();
```

If I remove the last line, the application runs without error. If a module referenced by main.ts imports more than one module, that works as well. I'm referencing the systemjs and typescript npm modules in my index.html file.

Comment: Hmm, wondering if there is just a problem with one of the files being imported?  https://plnkr.co/edit/cSvM16PXGGazc1ehx4Du?p=preview